# GeoServer function PointN doesn't work in YSLD

Tags: geoserver, sld, ysld

I did some tests and want to confirm if function `PointN` doesn't work in YSLD. For example below YSLD doesn't display any label:

```
name: style
feature-styles:
- name: style
  rules:
  - name: style
    symbolizers:
    - text:
        uom: metre
        geometry: ${pointN(geometry,1)}
        label: ${geometryType(geometry)}
        placement: point
        fill-color: '#000088'
        font-family: Tahoma
        font-size: 0.5
```

Change the geometry and label part to display geometry type also won't display any label:

```
geometry: ${geometry}
label: ${toWKT(pointN(geometry,1))}
```

But changing label to `${getX(pointN(geometry,1))}` will display always 0.0 regardless of number of point we enter:

```
geometry: ${geometry}
label: ${getX(pointN(geometry,1))}
```

I was looking already for YSLD binaries but I've found only GeoServer binaries.

Comment: You can also check the SLD generated by the YSLD parser to see if what that looks like

Comment: Can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: look in the styles directory - there should be a matching `.sld` file

Comment: Sorry, there is no matching sld file inside my workspace/styles directory and main styles directory.